# Question about bilinear form on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to verify the following

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $a(\cdot,\cdot)$ be a real continuous bilinear form on $H$

Then, define the operator $A:H-> H'$ as
$Au(v) :=a(u,v), v\in H$

Also, define the operator $B:H->H'$ as
$Bu(v) :=a(v,u), v\in H$.

Then, I want to show that A is surjective if and only if B is injective.

Here is my attempt:

Assume A is surjective. Let $w,z \in H$ such that $Bw(v) = Bz(v), v\in H$. That is, $a(\cdot,w) = a(\cdot,z)$.

By using surjectivity of A, then I can find $s$ and $t$ in $H$ such that $a(s,\cdot) = a(\cdot,w)$ and $a(t,\cdot) = a(\cdot,z)$.

Then, I somehow want to conclude that z = w, but I am not sure how what to do next.

How should I proceed?

Comment: This may be a bit easier if we use the Riesz representation theorem as applied to bilinear forms.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom What do you mean by "as applied to bilinear forms"? I know the Riesz Theorem for the general Hilbert case

Comment: I mean that we can find a bounded $T:H \to H$ such that $a(x,y) = \langle x, Ty \rangle$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one direction:

Assume $A$ is surjective.  That is, for every $f \in H'$, there exists a $u \in H$ such that
$$
a(u, \cdot) = f(\cdot)
$$
Now, suppose that $v,w \in H$ are such that $B(v) = B(w)$, that is, $a(\cdot,v) = a(\cdot,w)$.

That is, for every $u$, we have $a(u,v) = a(u,w)$.  By surjectivity, this implies that for every $f \in H'$, we have $f(v) = f(w)$.  This in turn implies that $v = w$ (why? [we could use this, for example,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_Separation_Theorem) but that's overkill.  Riesz representation could work here).  Thus, $B$ is injective.

---

**Riesz representation approach:** For every $f \in H'$, we have $f(v) = f(w)$.  Thus, for every $x \in H$, we have $\langle v,x \rangle = \langle w,x \rangle$.  So, we have
$$
\langle v,x \rangle = \langle w,x \rangle \qquad \forall x \in H \implies\\
\langle v,x \rangle - \langle w,x \rangle = 0 \qquad \forall x \in H \implies\\
\langle v-w,x \rangle = 0 \qquad \forall x \in H \implies\\
\langle v-w,v-w \rangle = 0 \implies\\
\|v -w\|^2 = 0
$$

Comment: Could you please show how you would use Riez representation to show $v = w$? I am just doing a  baby step with functional analysis, so it would be very helpful if you could show that

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: In your Riesz rep approach, you are considering every linear functional of the form $<\cdot,x> , x\in H$, so I guess even if I do not know $<\cdot,x> \in H'$ gives every continuous linear functional on H, the proof would still go through?

Comment: That is, we do not really need the "representation" aspect. we just need to know $<\cdot,x>$ is a continuous linear functional?

Comment: We need to know that the particular functional $\langle \cdot,v-w\rangle$ is hit by $A$. So you're right! No representation required.

Comment: Great! I got it!!!